# Detecting if ranges overlap - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a script which aims to detect of gaps between genes along chromosomes, the coordinates of these gaps and assign a category to the gap.

It takes an input file in this format:

```
Chr     start   finish  dir
chrI    335     649     +
chrI    538     792     +
chrI    1807    2169    -
chrI    2480    2707    +
chrI    7235    9016    -
chrI    10091   10399   +
chrI    11565   11951   -
chrI    12046   12426   +
chrI    13363   13743   -
chrI    21566   21850   +
chrI    22395   22685   -
chrI    24000   27968   -
chrI    31567   32940   +
chrI    33448   34701   +
```

Script:

```
k = 0;
for i=1:(length(start)-1)
    if start(i+1)<finish(i)
        continue
    else
    end
    k = k+1;
    IGR(k,1) = finish(i)+1;
    IGR(k,2) = start(i+1)-1;
    if dir{i}=='+' && dir{i+1}=='-'
        type{k,1} = 'Convergent';
    end
    if dir{i}=='+' && dir{i+1}=='+'
        type{k,1} = 'Tandem';
    end
    if dir{i}=='-' && dir{i+1}=='+'
        type{k,1} = 'Divergent';
    end
    if dir{i}=='-' && dir{i+1}=='-'
        type{k,1} = 'Tandem';
    end
end
```

This works well for the above input, however the check to determine whether or not adjacent genes overlap `if start(i+1)<finish(i)` fails if more than 2 are overlapping. The input below fails to work correctly as the input data is sorted by `start` thus it fails to detect that the third gene overlaps the first - checking only if genes 2 and 3 overlap.

```
chrII   280     2658    -
chrII   646     1128    +
chrII   2582    2899    -
chrII   2997    5009    -
chrII   5790    6125    +
chrII   7605    7733    -
```

The desired output would be for the system to detect genes 1-3 all overlap each other and thus to ignore them - with the first gap being detected between genes 3 and 4:

[image]

The red blocks signify the areas I am trying to detect whilst ignoring genes which overlap (as they produce no gaps). The blue blocks show each individual gene for the beginning of chrII.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a more robust way to check overlaps?

**EDIT**:

My full input file has genes sorted by chromosomes i.e.:

```
Chr     start   finish  dir
chrI    335     649     +
chrI    538     792     +
chrI    1807    2169    -
chrI    2480    2707    +
chrI    7235    9016    -
chrII   280     2658    -
chrII   646     1128    +
chrII   2582    2899    -
chrII   2997    5009    -
chrII   5790    6125    +
chrII   7605    7733    -
```

Any method of detecting overlap must not cross chromosome boundaries and once chrI ends and chrII begins, the process has to be refreshed such that the last gene on chrI is not checked against the first gene on chrII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it suffice to change the 3rd line of your script to

```
if start(i+1)<max(finish(1:i))
```

Using your second set of example data, I get the following output:

```
2900-2996: Tandem
5010-5789: Divergent
6126-7604: Convergent
```

This is what you wanted?

Balle

Comment: This appears to work well for individual chromosomes but when trying to process the full input (see EDIT), it breaks and produces considerably less values in `IGR` and `type` than is correct.

Comment: Assuming that the data is sorted first on `chr` then on `start`, you could just add an initial test where you check if current `chr` is different from the one you had last. If it has changed, remember the current position (say we call it `index_of_last_chromosome_end`) by setting itequal to the `i` where the change occurs. Then, the if-statement will read `if start(i+1)<max(finish(index_of_last_chromosome_end:i))` and I (believe - did not test) it should work.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I assume you already have start and finish values of each range in two vectors:

```
start = [ 280
          646
          2582
          2997
          5790
          7605 ];
finish = [ 2658
           1128 
           2899
           5009
           6125
           7733 ];
```

Now, **two ranges overlap if and only if each of them starts before the other has finished**. So

```
overlap = bsxfun(@lt, start(:), finish(:).'); %'// or @le to include equality
overlap = overlap & overlap.';
```

gives a square, symmetric matrix `overlap`, such that `overlap(m,n)` is `1` if ranges `m` and `n` overlap. You may want to remove the diagonal (a range obviously overlaps with itself, but that's not interesting):

```
overlap(1:numel(start)+1:end) = 0;
```

The result, for the example output, is

```
overlap =
     0     1     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

which tells you that ranges 1 and 2 overlap, and also ranges 1 and 3 overlap (note, however, that ranges 2 and 3 don't overlap).

Comment: Interesting approach! I am struggling to decide how best to incorporate this into my script within the for loop, any suggestions?

Comment: To use it in your loop, if I understand correctly, at each iteration `i` you need a single row of my `overlap` matrix,  namely the `i`-th row. So you could precompute `overlap` out of the loop, and then within the loop use something like `if any(overlap(i,1:i-1))`, or `if any(overlap(i,i+1))`, depending on what you want to check

Comment: Either one still produces an incorrect result for the chrII data - the first entry in `IGR` should be `2900 2906` but it is `1129 2581`.

Comment: I have added a diagram to the OP to hopefully clarify the requirements of the overlap detection.